Adding ACF Repeater Fields to the wordpress user role and retrieve that data

So I have created a repeater field using ACF Pro under all user role, I want admin to add data for each user from backend and using the repeater.
Now I want to display those data in the frontend.
Noe the problem is the usual repeater field code is not working for user role data retrive.
Can someone please help me??
Check the screenshot here

I have used the repeater field code, for user data retrive but it's not working

You can follow this docs:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-user/
<?php if( have_rows('repeater', 'user_1') ): ?>
        
            <ul>
        
            <?php while( have_rows('repeater', 'user_1') ): the_row(); ?>
        
                <li><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></li>
        
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            </ul>

<?php endif; ?>

